# Virtual Reality Like Dulux APP in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, augmented-reality, google-vr

I want to develop Hybrid APP like [dulux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cethar.dcs.duluxcolour&hl=en) .
 I have checked for [Google Virtual Reality](https://developers.google.com/vr/) but it is working for native only.
  I have checked for  wikitude also but i don't have too much idea that it will work on image recognition.

Comment: you can do in cross domain hybrid app, but you need to create your custom plugin which can connect native platform and will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for reply @natik .I have that solution  to make api but main prob is to create api .I didn't develop any api yet .Is there any other solution for this ?